# Mysql join query; what is it and how do i implemented it?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables: 'purchases' and 'orders'.

The purchases table has purchase_id as primary key and stores the customer_id and purchase details like total.

The 'orders' table stores all the item details related to each purchase, so it has purchase_id, stock_id, quantity, etc..

I want to implement a query which selects the purchase details from the 'purchases' table and item details from the 'orders' table. Both tables share the 'customer_id' column. I have been searching on the internet and have found that the query i'm looking for is called JOIN. However, I do not know which JOIN query to use (ie: INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN etc..) and I'm struggling to understand how it works even through I've looked at examples on w3schools.  Could someone help?

Comment: post some data and table on http://sqlfiddle.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This selects all the orders with the id 1 and all of it's related purchases.

```
SELECT * FROM orders LEFT JOIN purchases ON purchases.purchase_id = orders.purchase_id WHERE orders.order_id = 1;
```

The difference between `INNER JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN` is that if there is no purchase for one order, the `LEFT JOIN` will return the order with it's purchase column to null. The `INNER JOIN` won't return any row if the order does not have a purchase.

Answer (score 1):

A JOIN is used to combine rows from two or more tables.

INNER JOIN-  returns all rows where the "JOIN" is found and returns a result table.

```
SELECT table1.column1, table2.column2
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.common_field = table2.common_field;
```

LEFT JOIN- like it says returns the rows from the "left table" even if there are no matches found in the right table.

```
SELECT table1.column, table2.column2
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.common_field = table2.common_field;
```

There is a video on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lZ3FTPQssu4) that explains this much better